# Get old values before the scroll happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

if a write a javascript that onscroll add certain css to the DOM but when the user goes back after scrolling , to the header section of the page it should take the default css applied to it when the page was loaded at first .Yes i can write after function so that is scroll is 0 then the css should change but how can achieve that without writing it and simply inherit the basic style applied to it in the css when user scrolls and the comes back to the header again

Comment: You need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, unless you keep track of the inline style that you've added.

It's probably better to just add classes that you can later remove.

Or you can remove all inline style by setting it to empty with jQuery:

```
$('*').attr('style', '');
```